Error Installing azure-iot-hub on Python 3.11 macOS Sonoma. Seeking Fixes or Alternatives?
I am using Python 3.11 on an Apple M2 Max with macOS Sonoma Version 14.3.1. I encountered this error when I was trying to install azure-iot-hub, since uamqp is a dependency. This issue is  mentioned here: https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/issues/1511. I am looking for any fixes or alternatives for azure-iot-hub package since it is nor maintained for 2 years so far.
(venv) user@userxxxx % pip install azure-iot-hub                       
Collecting azure-iot-hub
  Using cached azure_iot_hub-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting msrest<1.0.0,>=0.6.21 (from azure-iot-hub)
  Using cached msrest-0.7.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (21 kB)
..
..
..
Building wheels for collected packages: uamqp
  Building wheel for uamqp (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for uamqp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
..
..
..
 uamqp/c_uamqp.c:65557:146: error: incompatible function pointer types passing 'void (void *, enum MESSAGE_RECEIVER_STATE_TAG, enum MESSAGE_RECEIVER_STATE_TAG)' to parameter of type 'ON_MESSAGE_RECEIVER_STATE_CHANGED' (aka 'void (*)(const void *, enum MESSAGE_RECEIVER_STATE_TAG, enum MESSAGE_RECEIVER_STATE_TAG)') [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
        __pyx_t_1 = ((struct __pyx_vtabstruct_5uamqp_7c_uamqp_cMessageReceiver *)__pyx_v_receiver->__pyx_vtab)->create(__pyx_v_receiver, __pyx_v_link, __pyx_f_5uamqp_7c_uamqp_on_message_receiver_state_changed, ((void *)__pyx_v_callback_context)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(7, 23, __pyx_L1_error)
..
..
..
      35 warnings and 1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for uamqp
Failed to build uamqp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for uamqp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects


Another way is to use pip install azure-mgmt-iothub. what do you like to create/run using the Azure IoT hub


Error Installing azure-iot-hub on Python 3.11 macOS Sonoma. Seeking Fixes or Alternatives?

issue while trying to install the azure-iot-hub package due to a failed build for the uamqp dependency. This could be related to compatibility issues with Python 3.11 or macOS Sonoma.

Update dependencies, including pip, setuptools, and wheel, to their latest versions. Sometimes, outdated dependencies can cause build issues.

python3 -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate

pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

Instead of using pip, you could try installing the packages using other methods, such as conda if you have Anaconda or Miniconda installed:
conda install -c conda-forge azure-iot-hub


Another way is to use azure-mgmt-iothub.

The code for sending a message using the Azure IoT Python SDK
from azure.iot.device import IoTHubDeviceClient, Message
import random

CONNECTION_STRING = "YourDeviceConnectionString"
MESSAGE_TEMPLATE = "boogie_{}={}"

# Create an instance of the device client using the connection string
device_client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)

# Connect the device client
device_client.connect()

# Send 12 "boogie" messages with random numbers
for i in range(1, 13):
    value = random.randint(0, 150)
    message = Message(MESSAGE_TEMPLATE.format(i, value))
    device_client.send_message(message)
    print("Sent message: " + MESSAGE_TEMPLATE.format(i, value))

# Disconnect the device client
device_client.disconnect()


Using the Azure CLI to monitor events from an Azure IoT Hub
 az iot hub monitor-events --hub-name HubName    --device-id deviceid -g resoursegroupname


